# React.js mapping how to change a single element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code, so I have a component which renders a columns of intervals and I want to change the color of the table on click and drag but what happens is instead it changes everything... I'm a complete beginner, So I have really no idea how will I do that..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TableBody extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  intervalItems: this.props.intervalItems,
  flag: 0,
  bgColor: '',
};
}

_mouseDown() {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  flag: 1,
}));
}

_mouseUp() {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  flag: 0,
}));
}

_mouseDrag(iD) {
if (this.state.flag == 1) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    bgColor: 'green',
  }));
} else {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    bgColor: '',
  }));
}
}

render() {
const { dayItems, intervalItems } = this.props;

return (
  <tbody>
    {dayItems.map(v => (
      <tr key={v.id}>
        <th>
          <div>{v.day}</div>
        </th>

        {this.state.intervalItems.map((v, i) => (
          <td
            key={v.id}
            onMouseDown={() => this._mouseDown()}
            onMouseMove={() => this._mouseDrag()}
            onMouseUp={() => this._mouseUp()}
            className={`table-inside-default ${this.state.bgColor}`}
          >
            {v.interval}
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
);
}
}
```

export default TableBody;

Comment: can you tell what `dayItems`, `intervalItems` look like so that I could replicate your code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is that you're updating the color for all of your `<td>` tags at once. This is happening because they are all referencing the same piece of state, `this.state.bgColor`. When one `td` is changed, the component is re-rendered and all the elements pointing to `this.state.bgColor` will show up as the same color.

You might consider adding another property to your state, such as `this.state.activeItem`, and update it from your `_mouseDrag` function. Based on your `activeItem`, you can then set a designated color so that only that one is being updated. You might want to reset the `activeItem` in a separate function so that it gets cleared in between mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `_mouseUp()`, `_mouseDrag()` or_ `mouseDown()` functions you change the color on the TableBody element and every single `<td>` item is getting the color from that property, so the color isn't individual to each `<td>`.

What I suggest you to do is create a child component with the `<td>` so the color and other properties you put in the child component will be individual to each child element. It would be something like this:

```
class TableBody extends Components {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
      ...
      {this.state.intervalItems.map((v, i) => (
        <ItemTable item={v} />
      ))}
      </tbody>
    )
  }
}

class ItemTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: 0,
      bgColor: '',
    };
  }
  _mouseDown() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      flag: 1,
    }));
  }

  _mouseUp() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      flag: 0,
    }));
  }

  _mouseDrag(iD) {
    if (this.state.flag == 1) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        bgColor: 'green',
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        bgColor: '',
      }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <td
        key={item.id}
        onMouseDown={() => this._mouseDown()}
        onMouseMove={() => this._mouseDrag()}
        onMouseUp={() => this._mouseUp()}
        className={`table-inside-default ${this.state.bgColor}`}
      >
        {v.interval}
      </td>
    )
  }
}
```